# How to make Super-R active AND keep Super-L active? Bionic Beaver 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, shortcut-keys

Trying now Ubuntu-18.04, left Windows button on my laptop works now like Super-L. But Super-R just do nothing, which quite strange.
I searched a lot - how to make both Super keys active (just like in Windowses, but could find only ways to change active Super from L to R or even to other key, but how to make both of them active?
To be short - wants both Super-L and Super-R works. Can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried **variant of @PRATAP** - works great, but only one session, after any restarts its refreshes to default values. Tryed to add to Xmodmap.desktop file, but looks like right now some gnome-environment bug doesn't allow to consider that file on startup.
Tryed **variant of @vanadium** with #ksuperkey - it works, but reaction of Supers suddenly got uncosy delay ~0.5 sec, don't know why and it may be only with my system. Also this decision is not so simple and requires ksuperkey (~50 MB)
**Got resolved problem by editing file /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc** , where I had *reassigned RWIN key value to 'Super-L' instead of inactive 'Super-R'*
Thanks all for help, your answers helped me in finding a solution

Answer (score 0):

I only know a way using an extra utility that is not included in the Ubuntu software sources. The utility is [`ksuperkey`](https://github.com/hanschen/ksuperkey). It allows to remap modifier keys.

Install the utility and have the following command autostart when you log in. To this aim, you can create a .desktop file in your local `.config/autostart`folder and supply the following command on the `Exec=` line.

```
Exec=sh -c "sleep 0.3 ; ksuperkey -e 'Super_R=Super_L'"
```

The "sleep" command introduced a small delay (0.3 ms) before running the command.

This remaps the <kbd>Super Right</kbd> key to the <kbd>Super Left</kbd> key, making it behave the same.

The full `./config/autostart/ksuperkey.desktop` file may look as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Utility;
Comment=Map right Super key to left Super key
Exec=sh -c "sleep 0.3 ; ksuperkey -e 'Super_R=Super_L'"
GenericName=Launcher
Icon=keyboard
Name=ksuperkey
StartupNotify=false
Type=Application
Version=1.0
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=ksuperkey.desktop
```

Comment: IMHO instead of extra utilities to acheive "Super_R=Super_L" it is easy to add this command in StartUpApplicationsPreferences `xmodmap -e "keycode 134 = Super_L"` where 134 is the keycode of Physcial Key Super_R

Comment: @PRATAP for sure there must be ways at the system level, but I do not know how. So please elaborate as a answer, which should become the accepted one.

Comment: @PRATAP heeey! It worked just like a magic, one string to terminal - and done! Thanks)

Comment: I got this workaround when you raised the question.. but did not mention bcoz you want to keep Super_L and Super_R as it is and work as same.. but this way is only making two Super_L keys in your keyboard..

Comment: @vanadium I'll try your way, but looks like PRATAP has not bad variant, without extra files and delays. Anyway thanks for help

Comment: @PRATAP man, your method makes both window keys act like Super - and when work both, you can't actually clearly said, are you have two supers, or two Super-Ls or tow Super-Rs)) So it does not matter, but what does - we have one more active key on keyboard and its as logical as keyboard layout - two super buttons - two active super button) So thanks)

Answer (score 0):

There is another way of mapping `Super + R`:
Navigate to Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts.
Under `View and Customize Shortcuts` find `Search` and ct hange it to `Super+R`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uTPj.png (sorry, have no permission to embed images)